# Resize eventListener Edge

Tags: javascript, resize, microsoft-edge

I've currently encountered this issue on `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0` which I do not know how to solve.

I applied an event listener on the window in order to perform some resizing actions. This works perfectly on Chromium-based browsers and IE11. For some reason on Edge when I try printing out the `window.innerWidth` in the resize function it stops at `562px`. This means the event listener does not trigger when the window size goes under `562px`.

Did anyone encounter this issue before?

Comment: Who is going to work in a 560px wide window anyway? I'm not even sure the browser support such a narrow width at all

Answer (score 0):

I try to test the below code with the MS Edge legacy browser 44.18362.449.0, IE 11 browser, and Google Chrome browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div> 
    <script>         
    function displayWindowSize()
    {    
        var w = window.innerWidth;            
        var h = window.innerHeight;                
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + ", " + "Height: " + h;
    }   
    window.addEventListener("resize", displayWindowSize);   
    displayWindowSize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Based on my test result, I noticed that the MS Edge legacy browser can minimum show the 562 px of window width but user can still decrease the size by resizing the window width but the MS Edge legacy browser will keep displaying the width 562 px.

Generally, the browsers stop resizing at some point and it shows that value as a height or width. Here, the issue is that the MS Edge legacy browser shows the minimum 562 px of width but the user can still decrease the window width.

I suggest you press ALT + J key in the MS Edge legacy browser window and it will launch the Feedback hub. You can try to provide feedback regarding this issue.